# Selecting features in QGIS via NetworkAPI HTTP POST request

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, rest, http-post, qgis-networkapi

Searching for a way to remotely operate on a running QGIS instance I recently stumbled upon a GSOC 2017 project **NetworkAPI** which provides a REST interface for QGIS (https://gitlab.com/qgisapi/networkapi). Installation and creating a new project via http request works fine, directly from Firefox adress bar as well as with Firefox REST Easy addon:

```
http://localhost:8090/qgis/newProject
```

[image]

What I want to do is remotely select features of a certain layer but unfortunatly NetworkAPI does not implement `mapLayer.selectByExpression()` directly. Thus I tried to use

```
http://localhost:8090/qgis/processing/runalg?alg=qgis:selectbyexpression
```

with REST Easy at first with no parameters, which returns an error

```
[
  "Error: Wrong number of parameters", 
  "ALGORITHM: Select by expression", 
  "\tLAYERNAME <ParameterVector>", 
  "\tEXPRESSION <ParameterString>", 
  "\tMETHOD <ParameterSelection>", 
  "", 
  "", 
  "METHOD(Modify current selection by)", 
  "\t0 - creating new selection", 
  "\t1 - adding to current selection", 
  "\t2 - removing from current selection", 
  "\t3 - selecting within current selection", 
  ""
]
```

as expected which basically means to me that this approach is at least promising.

Following the documentation from line 101 of https://gitlab.com/qgisapi/networkapi/blob/master/functions_processing.py

*"...The arguments to the processing algorithm should be passed in JSON format in the POST body of the request, and the request MUST specify 'Content-Type: application/json' in its header. The body should either be a simple JSON array (passed to the algorithm as positional arguments in that order) or as a JSON object containing all desired arguments as 'name: value' pairs...."*

I tried to set up REST Easy as shown in the image below

[image]

but this is just causing a `NetworkAPI connection timed out afer 3000ms`.

NetworkAPI Log Messages panel:

```
2018-09-10T16:02:34 0   Listening on port 8090
2018-09-10T16:02:34 0   Processing connection #6 (127.0.0.1)
2018-09-10T16:02:34 0   Connection opened...
2018-09-10T16:02:34 0   readyRead() was signalled before full HTTP request line was available for reading (0 bytes in buffer)
2018-09-10T16:02:34 0   Still busy with #6, putting incoming connection on hold...
2018-09-10T16:02:34 0   Connection opened...
2018-09-10T16:02:34 0   Processing request: received 3 of 423
2018-09-10T16:02:37 1   Connection timed out after 3000ms
2018-09-10T16:02:37 0   Disconnecting #6 (127.0.0.1)
2018-09-10T16:02:37 0   Listening on port 8090
```

Do I do the POST request the right way and are my parameters correct (tried with and without quotes, no difference)?